# Google Sheets - how do you use LOOKUP and SPLIT to map a list of row references to values

Tags: google-sheets, mapping, gs-vlookup

I am trying to setup a mapping of a list of values. One cell in a row contains a list of IDs or row numbers, and another cell in the same row contains a list of mapped values.

This is very simple with JOIN, ARRAYFORMULA and SPLIT if you are doing some basic math, for example:

```
A1: =1,2,3
A2: =JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(SPLIT(A1,",")+1)) 
A2: displays "2,3,4" (correct)
```

This does not seem to work robustly with LOOKUP and SPLIT (also tried LOOKUP and REGEXEXTRACT).  Specifically, I can get it to work, even with variable parameters, but as soon as I change the rows the values break. Example:

```
A column: ids (e.g. 1,2,3,4)
C column: names (e.g. "Apple", "Banana", "Custard")
E7: =1,2,3
F7: =JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(SPLIT($E7, ","), $A:$A, $C:$C)))
F7 displays "Apple,Banana,Custard" (correct)
```

The above is correct behaviour.  However, if I drag row 1 (id 1) to a different place, the formula breaks.

```
F7 displays "#N/A Did not find value `1` in LOOKUP evaluation"
```

The behaviour is not specific to LOOKUP or SPLIT, as I have also tried it with VLOOKUP and REGEXEXTRACT (in fact, with REGEXEXTRACT it is more difficult to support variable list size).

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l_sFvYTTcOL7Mf2pC1bG-Ia97jvGkWtgt3dcorKx0Ag/edit?usp=sharing)

**SOLUTION**

It works when using "=ROW()."  The actual problem, as pointed out by AdamL, is that the is_sorted flag needs to be false (if you want to support drag & drop)

```
E7: =ROW(A2)&","&ROW(A3)&","&ROW(A4)
F7: =JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(SPLIT($E7, ","), $A:$C, 3, 0)))
F7 displays correct value even after dragging row 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is: when you drag and drop, the lookup list is no longer sorted, and LOOKUP, along with VLOOKUP without FALSE (or 0) specified for the (optional) fourth argument, requires a sorted list. So I think the solution is to use VLOOKUP, but with the fourth argument specified:

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN(",",VLOOKUP(SPLIT($E5,","),$A:$D,3,0)))`

Comment: Wow, I have been always ignoring that parameter. I was unconsciously expecting "is_sorted" to default to false, but can appreciate it's perhaps a big optimization so is defaulted to true.   Gotta love when the solution is simple. Awesome!